# How to return counting of first N natural numbers using while loop

Tags: python, while-loop, return

I need to return the count of first N natural numbers using a while loop.

My code is:

```
def count_until(seconds):
    cnt=seconds
    while(cnt):
        cnt-=1
        return str(cnt)

print(count_until(10))
```

It is returning `9`
but I want the result to be like this: `9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1`

My other similar code with a `print` statement works perfectly fine:

```
def count_until(seconds):
    cnt=seconds
    while(cnt):
        cnt-=1
        print(str(cnt))
count_until(10)
```

Can I make the code with a return statement?

Answer (score 1):

Don't return the count instead append it to string and output it

```
def count_until(seconds):
    cnt=seconds
    out = ""
    while(cnt-1):
        cnt-=1
        out+=" " + str(cnt)
    return out

print(count_until(10))
```

Comment: Why use a while loop when it can be simplified?

Comment: As it was mentioned in the question, he/she required a while loop.

Comment: Yes, it works but what I recommend you is to provide other solutions as well which would be more efficient and easy.

Answer (score 0):

Does this solve the problem ?

```py
def count_until(seconds):
    s=""
    for i in range(seconds):
        s+=str(seconds-i)+" "
    return s
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't `return` something from a function and `recursively` call that function again. Hence, your second approach works. Here is a better version of your approach:

```
def natural_numbers(n):
    return ', '.join([str(num) for num in reversed(range(1,n+1))])
print(natural_numbers(10))
```

**What did I do above?**

- Using `reversed` runs the `range` in opposite order
- `1` and `n+1` are done since you want to include the number passed and since `0` is not a natural number
- List comprehension to make things easy.

Here's your code in `while loop` **(NOT RECOMMENDED)**:

```
def natural_numbers(n):
    string = ""
    while n:
        string+=str(n)+", "
        n-=1
    return string[:-2] # -2 to remove the ending ', ' you can change it to dynamically
    # return ', '.join([str(num) for num in reversed(range(1,n+1))])
print(natural_numbers(10))
```

*You can replace the `,`  with   as per your need*

Comment: I used a `for loop` since I would not recommend while loops.